# Pass the knockout model as data in an ajax call

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I have a knockout model with 44 observables.  User selects value for the observable and clicks on the Submit button.  The Submit button executes the StoreInDB.  I want to pass all 44 as a json string.  I tried to pass ko.toJSON($root, null, 2), but it does not work.

```
var TestModel = function() {
   self.Feedback1 = ko.observable();
   self.Feedback2 = ko.observable();
   self.Feedback3 = ko.observable();
   .
   .
   .
   self.Feedback44 = ko.observable();

   self.StoreInDB = function() {
                   $.ajax({
                             type:"POST"
                             url: url,
                             data:
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                             dataType: "json",
                    });
  };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ko.toJSON(self)` to get the JSON. See this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/u4a3K/